# Who figured out Rand's fate and how?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

Re-reading A Memory Of Light again, and something that didn't bother me so much in the first read-through is that several key folks (his ladies plus Alivia) seemed to know Rand's fate before it happened.

> All of the Happy Harem, plus Alivia, and maybe others seem to know that Rand and Moridin switched bodies.  While after death this would make sense (as they continue to sense the bond), none of them were at his side when he was dying, none seemed worried, and Alivia had set up all the equipment and horse and such before he woke up.

I realize that there could be a few explanations for this, but has there been anything published  by the author(s) or during interviews that indicate how this happened?

Comment: @Radhil They were, and I mentioned that in the spoiler text, but the question is that it seems they knew what was going on before that would've told them anything.

Comment: Sorry, brain banana-peeled past that part.  More coffee...

Answer (score 1):

Throughout the books, there are many places where Rand fulfils the prophecies of the Karaethon Cycle by knowing it in advance

- > The Stone of Tear will never fall, till Callandor is wielded by the Dragon’s hand

  Knowing this part, Rand sets out to Tear and fulfils the line.
- > Into the heart he thrusts his sword, into the heart, to hold their hearts

  He does this too with Callandor, on purpose to fulfil the prophecy.
- > chains the Shadowsworn to his will from the city, lost and forsaken

  I don't remember if he did this remembering the prophecy, but it could be possible.
- > The unstained tower, broken, bends knee to the forgotten sign

  Knowing this he forces some to swear loyalty to him.
- > He shall bind the nine moons to serve him

  Rand knew this when he started negotiations with the Daughter of the Nine Moons.

---

There are two parts of the Karaethon Cycle that refers to the Last Battle:

> ...yet shall the Dragon Reborn confront the Shadow at the Last Battle, and his blood shall give us the Light

and

> His blood on the rocks of Shayol Ghul, washing away the Shadow, sacrifice for man’s salvation

This is interpreted as the Dragon Reborn dying in the Last Battle throughout the books. And these lines have Rand troubled on several occasions. But it actually doesn't say that he will die straight out, it only says that he will bleed.

They all knew of the wound Rand had since long, that could never be healed even by Nynaeve.

In addition, Min has vision telling that Alivia will help Rand die. See the [wiki about Alivia](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Alivia).

So it seems obvious that the end was something planned in advance by Rand, Min, Alivia and the others, to fulfil the Karaethon Cycle and Min's vision both.

Comment: These statements are all true, but I don't see how they lead to what you're calling an "obvious" conclusion.

Comment: @Paul Because the lines Rand cared the most of in the whole Cycle where the ones predicting his death. If he planned ahead on all these other cases, why wouldn't he do so when it mattered the most? Then of course the characters' (lack of) reaction itself is proof enough.